# Use username + password to authentifikate to svn via ssh

Tags: ssh, svn

I have a Debian server running SVN version 1.8.

Now I want to give secure access to the users via ssh, but without creating all the users as users on the system.

So [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html) is basically a solution. But it uses separate private keys to detect different users. The Problem is, that the actual users are not familiar with private key authentication. They want to have a username and a password even if it makes no scene.

Is there an option* to use username and password for authentification but not using systemusers and get the same result?

*) My number one solution would be a file with `usrename = password` just like if you use svnserve without ssh. Is that possible?
Also using DAV is not an option, because we use nginx already and dont want to have apache beside it.

Comment: My opinion? Educate your users. There's no good reason any modern software Dev shouldn't be at least somewhat familiar with key authentication.